# How do I remove a stuck volume from a USB flash drive that has no partitions?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, diskpart

We have a USB flash drive that will not work with our computer image software.

I used `diskpart clean` but it is not cleaning the drive fully.  There are no partitions on the drive yet it lists a 0 size volume and mounts it.

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
Volume 3     D                       Removable       0 B  Unusable
```

I can create a new volume which takes volume 3's place but after removal the above remains and I cannot remove this "ghost" volume completely.

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
The object is not found.
```

This is a 3rd party store branded flash drive so I don't have any utilities available to reset it.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace the usb drive, it has failed

Comment: Most likely true.  Seems to still work okay we just can't get the software to load the image onto it I'm assuming because of this issue.  If I don't get anything useful in a couple days I'll replace it.